# My Geckos Head Still Has Skin On It!

Tags: leopard-geckos

My Leopard Gecko started shedding two days ago and stil has its head covered in dead skin. This is my first gecko and I don't know what to do he is trying to get it off it is loose but if I have to help I want to do it right to not injure him 
[image]

Comment: I don't know what exactly I'm looking at here.  You should retake the picture.